# making multiple tables with for loop

Tags: tables, loops

I have a following problem: I need to create a multipage document, containing single table on each page.
The table is same for all pages, pages differ from each other by page number only.
To make the generation of the document easier, I tried to define a table and then "multiply" it with `\tikz \foreach` directive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{ \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
Username & Sample & Filename & Sequence & Comments \\ \hline
 & & & & \\
 & & & & \\
\end{tabular}
}}
\end{document}
```

However, in this case there is no tet in table and loop doesn't work at all, if `\newpage` is used after the table.
Why does the `\foreach` fails to work, or may be there is more proper way making such document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, not fragments.

You had only put a word space between each table so they come side by side, you want at least `\par` or perhaps a forced page break. Also you don't want the `\tikz` command as that wraps the construct in a box and prevents page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
Username & Sample & Filename & Sequence & Comments \\ \hline
 & & & & \\
 & & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\par\newpage
}

\end{document}
```